# Please give us the no-AI banner

Tags: support, status-completed

Per [the announcement on network-wide meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396626/proposed-changes-to-help-center-articles-to-include-mention-of-ai-generated-cont), we need to specifically request the right banner UI, stating that AI-generated content is disallowed — the policy we landed on [in this discussion](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/policy-on-chatgpt-generated-posts). (Otherwise, we'll get one saying that it needs to be cited.)

Comment: Please let's get the banner.

Comment: For clarity: the current version of the roll-out plan says _no banner_ will be rolled out by default, so the "opt-out" would be to ensure the new Help Center article actually reflects this community's policy. Which brings me to: Is there consensus on that being this community's stance on GenAI content? I couldn't find a previous discussion on the issue on Meta.

Comment: @JNat Yes, see https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/policy-on-chatgpt-generated-posts.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Stephie — added in to the question's body for visibility! ^_^

Comment: @JNat did we get the wrong [help](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy)?

Comment: Indeed you did, @Stephie, due to oversight on my part. For what it's worth, the relevant help center article is mod-editable, so you should be able to tweak it to suit this community's needs.

Answer (score 1):

I've just enabled the banner, as requested. Additionally, I've edited the relevant help center article to reflect the site's policy, by using the template provided in the MSE post mentioned in the question.